# UITableView with UIWebView in each cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I would like to have a `UITableView` with a `UIWebView` in each cell. The `UIWebView` should have the contentSize so that it shows its whole content without scrolling. My problem is the `HeightForRowAtIndexPath` because the content has to be loaded first before it can return a value.

Comment: why dont you update the height of the cell after getting the response?

Comment: Its just a local string, there is no response. I know I could update it after webViewDidFinishLoad but it gets called inside each cell and I don't know how to pass the values then etc

Comment: you will notice a little delay in loading webview inside cell if you will add webview inside a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something like this in this old and maybe no more up-to-date code:
https://github.com/Daij-Djan/DDUtils/tree/master/ui/M42WebviewTableViewCell%20%5Bios%5D

Disclaimer: My own open source code

How it works:
In the dataSource:

1. you return the cell's preferredHeight (which is 0 if there is no content)
2. you also implement the delegate `- (void)tableCellDidLoadContent:(M42WebviewTableViewCell*)cell;`
3. you reload your table which will invalidate all Heights. When you now return preferredHeight it is valid and the views appear alright.

Comment: just for the record: I modernised the code and also included a functional demo app

Answer (score 1):

I would subclass UITableViewCell in this (very MVC) way:

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic,strong) id model;

+(CGFloat)heightForModel:(id)model;

@end
```

Model can be whatever your want. This is a very generic example.
In **heightForModel** you calculate the exact height of the cell.

In the **init** method of **CustomTableViewCell**, you should add a blank UIWebView to the cell.
When you "set" **model** property, you should refresh cell UI.

Then in the class that implements the delegate methods (assuming that cell models are stored in a **NSArray** called **models**):

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [CustomTableViewCell heightForModel:self.models[indexPath.row]];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([CustomTableViewCell class])];

    cell.model = self.models[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Remember to register your custom cell!